# What's the meaning of "games impedimenta" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The Parsonses's flat was bigger than Winston's (...). Everything had a battered, trampled-on look, as though the place had just been visited by some large violent animal. Games impedimenta - hockey sticks, boxing gloves (...) - lay all over the floor (...).

If "impedimenta" are things that impede, then "games impedimenta" are things that impede to play games, right? But this logic doesn't seem to be working here.

PS Shouldn't there be a comma after "large" in "large violent animal"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does mean *equipment*, especially bulky equipment, but you are right about the origins of the word.

According to [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=impedimenta) it meant:

"traveling equipment," c. 1600, from Latin impedimenta "luggage, military baggage," literally "hindrances," on the notion of "that by which one is impeded;" plural of impedimentum "hindrance"